# How to write ternary operator logic for multiple conditions and for optional param?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

trying to write logic for my validator functions that has objects we use as errorMap for the input validation , For below logic `args.drugName` is optional field if user provide text we just want to make sure its greater than 3 letters or in case of empty successCondition should be valid. So for the optional param in typescript how do we fix this issue ?

main.js

```
   {
                errorKey: ValidationErrorEnum.InvalidDrugName,
                successCondition: (args: DrugPriceParam) => {
                    let isValid: boolean = false;
                    isValid = args.drugName.length >= 3 ? true : _.isEmpty(args.drugName) ? true : false;

                    // if (args.drugName && args.drugName.length >= 3) {
                    //         isValid = true;
                    // } else if (_.isEmpty(args.drugName)) {
                    //     isValid = true;
                    // }
                    return isValid;
     }
```

Error;

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify the check to

```
return !args.drugName || args.drugName.length > 2;
//     if empty
//                       if longer then 2 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Its same as you write if condition

```
 (args.drugName && args.drugName.length >= 3) ? true : _.isEmpty(args.drugName) ? true : false;
```

There is new feature coming in js - optional chaining. you can use this currently using webpack plugin.
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Using this we can simply write

```
args?.drugName?.length >= 3 ? true : _.isEmpty(args.drugName) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're simply returning booleans, you don't actually need to use the ternary operator. You should be able to just pass the result of the comparison operations:

```js
// if (args.drugName && args.drugName.length >= 3) {
//     isValid = true;
// } else if (_.isEmpty(args.drugName)) {
//     isValid = true;
// }

// Becomes:

isValid = (args.drugName && args.drugName.length >= 3) || _.isEmpty(args.drugName);
```

Don't forget about short-circuiting, either: If the first half of the `||` is found to be true, then `_.isEmpty` won't even be run (and similarly, if the first half of the `&&` is found to be false, then `...length >= 3` won't even be run).